# Slideshow first slide timeout longer

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I have a custom image slideshow that I am having to modify. I am trying to make the first slide timeout longer, basically I want it to be visible 2 seconds longer than the others. What would be the best way to go about? Here is the code:

```
(function($) {

var settings = {
        'promoid': 'promo',
        'selectorid': 'promoselector',
        'promoanimation': 'fade',
        'timeout': 4500,
        'speed': 'slow',
        'go': 'true',
        'timeoutname': 'promotimeout'
};

$.fn.promofade = function(options) {
    settings.promoid = $(this).attr("id");

    return this.each(function() {   
        $.promofade(this, options);
    });
};

$.promofade = function(container, options) {

    if ( options ) {
        $.extend( settings, options );
    }

    var elements = $("#" + settings.promoid).children();
    var selectors = $("#" + settings.selectorid).children();

    if ( elements.length != selectors.length ) { alert("Selector length does not match."); }

    if ( settings.go == 'true' )
    {
        settings.timeoutname = setTimeout(function() {
                $.promofade.next(elements, selectors, 1, 0);
                }, settings.timeout);
    } else {
        clearTimeout( settings.timeoutname );
    }
};

$.promofade.next = function( elements, selectors, current, last ) {

    if ( settings.promoanimation == 'fade' )
    {
        //$(elements[last]).fadeOut( settings.speed );
        //$(elements[current]).fadeIn( settings.speed );
        $(elements[last]).hide();
        $(elements[current]).show();
    } else if ( settings.promoanimation == 'slide' ) {
        // This creates a 'slide gap', where they havent crossed yet, causing a blank spot
        // TODO: fix!
        $(elements[last]).slideUp( settings.speed );
        $(elements[current]).slideDown( settings.speed );
    }

    $(selectors[last]).removeClass("on");
    $(selectors[current]).addClass("on");
    //$(selectors[current]).attr("class", "on");

    // They are both the same length so we only calculate for one
    if ( (current + 1) < elements.length ) {
        current = current + 1;
        last = current - 1;
    } else {
        current = 0;
        last = elements.length - 1;
    }

    if ( settings.go == 'true' )
    {
        settings.timeoutname = setTimeout( function() {
            $.promofade.next( elements, selectors, current, last );
        }, settings.timeout );
    } else {
        clearTimeout( settings.timeoutname );
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

My html is built out like so:

```
<div id="fader">
    <a href="#"><img src="#" alt='#'/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="#" alt='#'/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="#" alt='#'/></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve it by specifying a separate first slide timeout that's assigned during initialization, then use the standard timeout on promofade.next.

```
(function($) {

    var settings = {
            'promoid': 'promo',
            'selectorid': 'promoselector',
            'promoanimation': 'fade',
            'firstslidetimeout':2000, //apply this during $.promofade only
            'timeout': 4500,
            'speed': 'slow',
            'go': 'true',
            'timeoutname': 'promotimeout'
    };

    $.fn.promofade = function(options) {
        settings.promoid = $(this).attr("id");

        return this.each(function() {   
            $.promofade(this, options);
        });
    };

    $.promofade = function(container, options) {

        if ( options ) {
            $.extend( settings, options );
        }

        var elements = $("#" + settings.promoid).children();
        var selectors = $("#" + settings.selectorid).children();

        if ( elements.length != selectors.length ) { alert("Selector length does not match."); }

        if ( settings.go == 'true' )
        {
            settings.timeoutname = setTimeout(function() {
                    $.promofade.next(elements, selectors, 1, 0);
                    }, settings.timeout + settings.firstslidetimeout);
        } else {
            clearTimeout( settings.timeoutname );
        }
    };

    $.promofade.next = function( elements, selectors, current, last ) {

        if ( settings.promoanimation == 'fade' )
        {
            //$(elements[last]).fadeOut( settings.speed );
            //$(elements[current]).fadeIn( settings.speed );
            $(elements[last]).hide();
            $(elements[current]).show();
        } else if ( settings.promoanimation == 'slide' ) {
            // This creates a 'slide gap', where they havent crossed yet, causing a blank spot
            // TODO: fix!
            $(elements[last]).slideUp( settings.speed );
            $(elements[current]).slideDown( settings.speed );
        }

        $(selectors[last]).removeClass("on");
        $(selectors[current]).addClass("on");
        //$(selectors[current]).attr("class", "on");

        // They are both the same length so we only calculate for one
        if ( (current + 1) < elements.length ) {
            current = current + 1;
            last = current - 1;
        } else {
            current = 0;
            last = elements.length - 1;
        }

        if ( settings.go == 'true' )
        {
            settings.timeoutname = setTimeout( function() {
                $.promofade.next( elements, selectors, current, last );
            }, settings.timeout);

        } else {
            clearTimeout( settings.timeoutname );
        }
    };
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: @JustinClarke This will only make the slider to wait longer for the first iteration, consider my answer if you need to make the timeout longer for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make changes in two places to get what you wanted.

```
(function ($) {
    var settings = {
        'promoid': 'promo',
        'selectorid': 'promoselector',
        'promoanimation': 'fade',
        'timeout': 4500,
        'firstAdditionalTimeout': 4500,
        'speed': 'slow',
        'go': 'true',
        'timeoutname': 'promotimeout'
    };

    $.fn.promofade = function (options) {
        settings.promoid = $(this).attr("id");
        return this.each(function () {
            $.promofade(this, options);
        });
    };

    $.promofade = function (container, options) {
        if (options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }
        var elements = $("#" + settings.promoid).children();
        var selectors = $("#" + settings.selectorid).children();
        //if (elements.length != selectors.length) {
        //    alert("Selector length does not match.");
        //}
        if (settings.go == 'true') {
            settings.timeoutname = setTimeout(function () {
                $.promofade.next(elements, selectors, 1, 0);
            }, settings.timeout + settings.firstAdditionalTimeout); // here 
        } else {
            clearTimeout(settings.timeoutname);
        }
    };

    $.promofade.next = function (elements, selectors, current, last) {

        if (settings.promoanimation == 'fade') {
            //$(elements[last]).fadeOut( settings.speed );
            //$(elements[current]).fadeIn( settings.speed );
            $(elements[last]).hide();
            $(elements[current]).show();
        } else if (settings.promoanimation == 'slide') {
            // This creates a 'slide gap', where they havent crossed yet, causing a blank spot
            // TODO: fix!
            $(elements[last]).slideUp(settings.speed);
            $(elements[current]).slideDown(settings.speed);
        }

        //$(selectors[last]).removeClass("on");
        //$(selectors[current]).addClass("on");
        //$(selectors[current]).attr("class", "on");

        // They are both the same length so we only calculate for one
        if ((current + 1) < elements.length) {
            current = current + 1;
            last = current - 1;
        } else {
            current = 0;
            last = elements.length - 1;
        }

        if (settings.go == 'true') {
            settings.timeoutname = setTimeout(function () {
                $.promofade.next(elements, selectors, current, last);
            }, current == 1 ? (settings.timeout + settings.firstAdditionalTimeout) : settings.timeout); // and here
        } else {
            clearTimeout(settings.timeoutname);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bp4nU/)